# nrwl/nx paths compatibility on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I got to know about `nrwl/nx` and started using it. I initialized a monorepo on Windows. There, I added my first app, a `react-native` app.

I noticed that there are a bunch of places that the entry file paths and some other file paths are defined as per Windows paths. (with `\`). My problem is if I migrate to Linux, and setup my monorepo on Linux, is there any way to make them work because Linux uses paths with `/` instead of `\`.

How I can assure of that?